# how do i write a format value in c++ like python?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <string>
#include <format>


using namespace std;

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main() {
    char* p = getenv("USERPROFILE");
    const char* dllpath = "C:\\Users\\{here i need to write p value but how?}\\Desktop\\ExterTi\\req\\sk.dll"; // here
    //cout << dllpath << endl;
    system("pause");

    

}
```

how to format values like python in c++? like ...

```
ip = "192.168.2.1"
print(f"ip => {ip}")   # output ip => 192.168.2.1
```

i mean i need to write customer's current c:\Users{currentUser}
i got it but i don't know how do i write this value

Comment: Use either [C++20 STL Formatting Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) or [Boost.Format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Don't forget [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Comment: Yeah, I'd replace boost with libfmt given that C++20's implementation is somewhat anemic and almost purpose defeating by still requiring `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
ip = "192.168.2.1"
print(f"ip => {ip}")   # output ip => 192.168.2.1
```

Please try storing these in the `string` data-type instead of `char*` for easier manipulation capabilities

Now assuming you have

```
string ip = "192.168.2.1";
```

If you wish to  print this, the simplest solution could be using the printf function to print your string, you could try

```cpp
printf("ip => %s\n", ip);
```

Of course, do not forget to

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
```

or

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
```

You could also just use

```cpp
cout<<"ip => "<<ip<<endl;
```

For printing formatted data to string,

```
sprintf(dllpath, "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\ExterTi\\req\\sk.dll", p);
```

should work, given dllpath is not a constant and initialized with an initial size, eg `char dllpath[500];`

Comment: i want to do:   const char* dllpath = "C:\\Users\\{here i need to write p value}\\Desktop\\ExterTi\\req\\sk.dll";

Comment: ```sprintf(dllpath, "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\ExterTi\\req\\sk.dll", p);```
You would need to ensure dllpath is not constant initially and has an initial size alloted, otherwise again, please use strings instead of char*